# Georeferencing postcodes into bubble map with Cartodb

Tags: carto, visualisation, thematic-map

I have recently discovered Cartodb and I am trying to create a bubble/thematic map of postcodes. I have a csv document with one column of postcodes from around the UK. I have uploaded the dataset and when georeferencing the data i choose from the postal code tab and enter United Kingdom as a country.

The issue is that only a handful of the post codes got georeferenced while the rest remain null. The postcodes are valid so not sure why it's not working.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

EDIT
here is an screenshot of the data, you can see a few have their long/lats while others don't

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GSE. You might want to add an example (screenshots / table) of what you're trying to achieve - this will make it easier to understand the issue.

Comment: I have added a screenshot, please let me know if there is anything else

Comment: the_geom is the field that is required for location so only the lat/lng values will work, CartoDB does not geocode GB postcodes. your better uploading Open Code-Point from Ordnance Survey https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html - you will have to re-project OSGB36 to WGS84 for lat/lng and not OS grid references.

Comment: to save reprojection use https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm CSV ukpostcodes.zip (33MB zipped, 96MB unzipped) but check the dates (16th November 2015) that is 2 updates behind OS releases.